# В каком заголовочном файле объявлено значение длины IP аддреса в *nix ?

Tags: сеть, c, unix, linux

Мне надо указать длину IPv4 аддреса. Однако заводить макрос вида **#define IPv4_ADDR_LENGTH 4** я не хочу. Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли в каком-нибуть стандартном *.h файле подобный макрос?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Опасаетесь, что текущий размер IPv4 адреса (4 байта) когда-нибудь изменится?

Макроса не знаю, но в netinet/in.h для адреса IPv4 определена структура

```
struct in_addr
  {
    in_addr_t s_addr;
  };
```

Соответственно sizeof(struct in_addr) дает желаемое значение.

Аналогично

```
  struct in_addr ipv4adr, *pipv4;
  int 
    len1 = sizeof(ipv4adr.s_addr),
    len2 = sizeof(pipv4->s_addr),
    len3 = sizeof((*pipv4).s_addr);
```

даст Вам тот же результат.